# Adding text to lowest level circle on transition in d3.js circle packing plot | updating style of text element of a specific class

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am learning both javaScript and d3.js so please bear with me.

Currently, I have a circle packing plot that lets you zoom into each level, making the text from the parent node disappear while making the text for the nodes of the current depth visible. Here is my code on plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/0UTZN084qZWkqn11?open=lib%2Fscript.js

My data is set up such that I have a top level node with name "", who is represented by the outer circle of class cirlce.node.node--root. Its children have the names "Animal tissue", "Water", and "Soil/sediment" and are represented by the circles of class circle.node. The orange circles are the bottom level represented by circle.node.node--leaf.

The issue is that when I zoom all the way into an orange circle.node.node--leaf, I want the text from its parent node to be visible instead of disappearing. I have tried manipulating the if statements for the transition function to keep the text from the node of height=0 when zooming further in... but this only works if you zoom into the node of height=0 as an intermediate step before zooming all the way into the leaf. This is the block of code I think I need to update (line 128 in the .html file in the plunker)

```
transition.selectAll("text")
    .filter(function(d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
    .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { 
        if ((d.parent === focus)) {
            return 1
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    })
    .on("start", function(d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
    .on("end", function(d) { 
        if ((d.parent !== focus)) {
            this.style.display = "none"
        } 
    });
```

I assume there is a way to add text to these circle.node.node--leaf guys, but I have not been able to figure it out.

## EDIT 2

I have changed the lowest level text elements to have a class of ".labelLow" and other text elements to have a class of ".label". So now I just need to figure out how I can update the style of the text elements with class ".labelLow". I have tried using d3.selectAll, but when it initiates, it removes the entire figure. The selectAll function is not behaving how I expected it to, here is the relavent code block (plunker link above is updated):

```
transition.selectAll("text")
            .filter(function(d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
            .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { 
                if ((d.parent === focus) || (focus.height === 0)) {
                    return 1
                } else {
                    return 0
                }})
            .on("start", function(d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
            .on("end", function(d) { 
                if ((d.parent !== focus) && (focus.height !== 0)) {
                    this.style.display = "none"
                } if (focus.height === 0) {
                    // my attempt at updating the style of a specific class
                    d3.selectAll(".labelLow")
                        .style("display", "inline")

                    this.parentNode.style.display = "none"
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with ended up having nothing to do with text elements having different class names. The key was really to look at this problem after a night of sleep to come up with cleaner logic for the if statments in the transition/zoom function AND knowing when I wanted to show the text for d OR the text for d.parent. Here is the updated code block:

```
transition.selectAll("text")
            .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
                // if your parents is the focus, or if you are zoomed all the way in, show text element
                if ((d.parent === focus) || ((d === focus) && (focus.height === 0))) {
                    return 1
                } else {
                    return 0
                }
            })
            
            .on("start", function(d) { if ((d.parent === focus) || (d === focus)) this.style.display = "inline"; })
            .on("end", function(d) { 
                if ((d.parent !== focus) && (focus.height !== 0)) {
                    this.style.display = "none"
                } if (focus.height === 0) {
                    // Update text elements with height=0 to be visible if they are the focus
                    d3.selectAll("text")
                        .filter(function(d) { return d.height === 0 })
                        .style("display",  function(d) {
                            if (d === focus) {
                                return "inline"
                            } else {
                                return "none"
                            }
                        })
                        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
                            if (d === focus) {
                                return 1
                            } else {
                                return 0
                            }
                        })
                    
                    // remove visibility of text elements at level we zoomed in from
                    this.style.display = "none"
                }
            })
```